# How to write the proper regular expression to extract value from the string?

Tags: r

```
> str="  9.48  12.89 13.9    6.79   "
> strsplit(str,split="\\s+")
[[1]]
[1] ""      "9.48"  "12.89" "13.9"  "6.79" 

> unlist(strsplit(str,split="\\s+"))->y
> y[y!=""]
[1] "9.48"  "12.89" "13.9"  "6.79"
```

How can i get it by a single regular expression with strsplit , not to oparate it with 
`y[y!=""]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract just the numbers perhaps following regex would do.

```
regmatches(str, gregexpr("[0-9.]+", text = str))[[1]]
## [1] "9.48"  "12.89" "13.9"  "6.79"
```

To capture -ve numbers you can use following

```
str = "  9.48  12.89 13.9    --6.79   "
regmatches(str, gregexpr("\\-{0,1}[0-9.]+", text = str))[[1]]
## [1] "9.48"  "12.89" "13.9"  "-6.79"
```

Comment: +1. Maybe add a dash in there for good measure to make sure you capture any negative numbers too.

Answer (score 2):

I would just trim the string before splitting it:

```
strsplit(gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", str), "\\s+")[[1]]
# [1] "9.48"  "12.89" "13.9"  "6.79"
```

Alternatively, it is pretty direct to use `scan` in this case:

```
scan(text=str)
# Read 4 items
# [1]  9.48 12.89 13.90  6.79
```

Comment: Agree with `scan()`. It's also an effective way to get input from screens where posters fail to use dput.